# Comparing multiple columns in multiple worksheets and color if found

Tags: if-statement

I am trying to compare 2 worksheets and 2 columns and then color the matches red.

For example,
Worksheet1
123 1.5
345 2.5
567 3.5
789 4.5

Worksheet2
124 1.5
367 2.5
567 3.5
891 4.5

I want to compare these worksheets and if column A in WK1 matches column A in WK2 and column B in WK1 matches column B in worksheet 2 color row red.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an IF statement to color the cel.  Use conditional formatting.

As far as getting the values from another file, use the following sytax:

```
='[fileName.xlsx]sheetName'!C22
```